# What's the range for rounded corner radius?

Tags: android, android-layout

I know how to use rounded corner for a view would be something like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

What is the range for radius? Is it 0 to 100 dp?

Comment: Have you considered to mark any asnwer as a correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "range". Dp means device pixels. So if your view is `100dp` the normal range would be from `0` to `50` (since setting a border radius larger than half of the width or height it would look rather weird).

But basically there is no limit.

Also taking into account that values above half the size will be treated like half the size (so a border radius of `1000dp` on a `100dp` image will still be only `50dp` border.)
And values below zero are the same as zero.

This gives you a nice option to always have completely round borders by defining a very large radius (hacky).

Comment: I would like to add infos about blocking radius to half the size of the element. It seems to be the case on Android 4.1 and lower, but I tested with emulator and devices from 4.3 to 6, and it seems like starting at 4.3 you are no longer limited to half the size of the view, without looking weird. For example, a View of size 50dp * 50dp with a top left and right corner radius of 50dp, and bottom corners with 0dp radius, will be shaped as a half-circle.

Answer (score 1):

There is no range. You can have any value as the radius, negative or positive values.

**Negative values** ( like `-40dp` ) has no effect on the corner radius. This is same as giving corner radius as `0dp`.
**Positive values** ( like `40dp` ) has an effect, but only up to half the size of the view. Anything more than that, then it remains the same. If the height of the view is `200dp`, then corner radius of `200dp` behaves the same way as `100dp`.

Answer (score 1):

As other guys already said, there's no range for `android:radius` property.

However, I'd suspect that you would need a round/circular shape *independent* of its size (width and height). If I'm right, you could use `oval` type shapes:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
        android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Using this way you should make sure alpha channel of `startColor` is `00`.

Answer (score -1):

> What is the range for radius?

There is **no range** on this attribute.

---

Explanation of your question :

> android:radius
>
> Dimension. The radius for all corners, as a dimension value or dimension resource. This is overridden for each corner by the following attributes.

That `Dimension resource` means the :

> A dimension value defined in XML. A dimension is specified with a number followed by a unit of measure. For example: 10px, 2in, 5sp.

For more information about [`android:radius`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) and [`Dimension Resource`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)